# Populating bootstrap-datepicker with Knockout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker widget, working great with Knockout: i.e., I can select a date, and the model is correctly updated. However, I cannot seem to be able to initially populate the date, when I first initialize my model.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-bind="datepicker: someDate" />
<div data-bind="text: someDate"></div>
```

And the corresponding JavaScript:

```
var self = this;

$('.datepicker').datepicker();    

ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }                
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
        var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (widget) {
            widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            widget.setValue();            
        }
    }
}; // end KO binding datepicker

function AppViewModel() {
    self.someDate = ko.observable(new Date('01/01/2004'));    
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

And the corresponding JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/philcms1/0mftjtk4/2/

How do I get the widget populated when the model is first bound?

Comment: You can check a working sample here http://jsfiddle.net/0mftjtk4/3/   (taken from http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2014/07/knockoutjs.html)

Comment: Thanks! I add missed the `value: someDate` in my binding. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Got any issue still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a working sample here [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0mftjtk4/3) (taken from [Codinglookseasy](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2014/07/knockoutjs.html))

As you said using `value: myDate` fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`value:someDate` is definitely a more explicit way to go but you could also just call jquery datepicker's setDate method in the init callback as shown in

http://jsfiddle.net/zkgp0b4b/1/

Comment: I am also trying to update the observable, using a timeout to simulate a deferred. It is updating the model, but not the widget: http://jsfiddle.net/philcms1/zkgp0b4b/2/. Any idea why?

Comment: i don't know what was wrong with your code but it is related to how the datepicker works and not knockout. http://jsfiddle.net/o22uy8wc/1/  Here is a version that sets the date in the same ways as was done in the init funciton